# Tensorflow in Python 3.8

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanted to add a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62013375/12389995, but I could not due to the lack of enough reputations. Since I cannot earn enough reputation to make comments at the moment I have to make a new topic as a follow-up to the existing topics or comments, So sorry for that.

My problem is, I want to install Tensorflow with pip on Python 3.8 inside of a virtual environment. But I get the following error message
Tensorflow Install Fail:

[image]

Is this my mistake?

I've tried different things as well such as:
pip install tensorflow==r2.2 and other versions but still fail.
I would like to have the GPU version and I followed the following instruction https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu up to the point where I had to install Tensorflow without problems.

Any help?

Kind regards.

EDIT:

The comment helped me and I accidentally had installed Python 32 Bit instead of 64 Bit. Thanks for the fast help!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390095/no-matching-distribution-found-for-tensorflow help?

Comment: Really big thank you. It was due to the fact, that I accidentally installed 32 Bit version instead of 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later.

So you can follow [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) and more detailed step-by-step [in here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to install TensorFlow 2.x to run in your Python 3.8